# How to configure heartbeat for spring-rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

How can I configure spring-rabbitmq connection-factory

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="${rabbitmq.host}" port="${rabbitmq.port:5672}"
    username="guest" password="guest"/>
```

With a requested heartbeat ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can provide the underlying connection factory as a bean, properties set on the rabbit:connection-factory will be overridden.

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="${rabbitmq.host}" port="${rabbitmq.port:5672}"
        username="guest" password="guest" connection-factory="rcf" />

<bean id="rcf" class="com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="${rabbitmq.host}"/>
        <property name="requestedHeartbeat" value="10" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. I would add it is configured in seconds.

Comment: hi mikkpatel am using class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory" for this how can i set the RequestedHeartBeat ??? can u help me please ??

Answer (score 0):

You should use `requestedHeartbeat` property for connectionfacory bean

```
<bean id="rabbitconnectionFactory" class="com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="requestedHeartbeat" value="100" />
</bean>
```